# Another galois theory problem. (quartic with dihedral Galois group)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Given:  If $f$ in $k[X]$ is an irreducible quartic and $G$ is the galois group of its splitting field, then $G$ is contained in $D_8$ iff the resolvent cubic of $f$ has a root in $k$.

Now suppose that $char(k)\neq 2$ and $k$ contains a square root of $-1$. Show that if $G\subset D_8$, roots of $f$ can be found with a square root of an element $\alpha\in k$ and a fourth root of an element of $k(\sqrt \alpha)$.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And your own thoughts on this are...

Comment: Okay, I have got this one. Thanks anyway.